# php table grid layout

Tags: php, html-table

I wanted to fetch data inside PHP table in grid layout. So I made this code. I don't know what went wrong or if I am missing something. I wanted the table to have three columns but it shows the table in a single column. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PAGINATION FILTER</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'conn.php';?>
<?php

    $stmt=$con->prepare('SELECT author, book_name, language FROM bk_tst_fltr ORDER BY id LIMIT 8');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($author, $book_name, $language);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $i=0;
    ?>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <?php
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        if($i % 3 == 0){
        ?><tr><td><?php echo $author,"\n</br>",$book_name,"\n</br>", $language ;?></td>
    <?php
    }}
    ?></tr></table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if($i % 3 == 0){` line is just making you only show every third result - or it would if you actually incremented the `$i` variable anywhere.

You probably want to use that logic to start a new row - but still output every row.

Try something like this:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10"><tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
while($stmt->fetch()){
    if ($i > 0 && ($i % 3 == 0)) { // every third row, but not the first time
        echo("</tr><tr>");
    }
    echo("<td>{$author}<br>{$book_name}<br>{$language}</td>");
    $i++;
}
?>
</tr></table>
```

At the very beginning, it starts a table and the first row - and then it outputs a new `<td>` cell from the `foreach` loop for every result that you find - and the `<tr>` is closed at the very end. That would result in all the results being side-by-side on a single row.

Then the final step is that before every third row (`$i % 3 == 0`) - but not the first time (`$i > 0`) we want to close the current row and start a new one: `</tr><tr>`.

There's a couple other minor issues that I fixed above as well:

1. You didn't actually increment the `$i` variable in your original code
2. You were starting a new `<tr>` for every result you output, but only closing one of them (at the very end, after the loop).
3. You were using `</br>` for newlines - which is not valid HTML. You want either `<br>` or `<br/>` instead.

Comment: Thank You very much for your explained answer

Comment: if i wanted to make this in div without using tables. How can i do that. because every website i see have this in div tag and some in li tags

Answer (score 0):

This method finishes up with the proper number of `<td>` tags, so that there are always 3 in each row (or 2 with a span of 2, when there is only 1 data item in the last row):

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $html = '';
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $html .= '<td>'.$author."\n</br>".$book_name."\n</br>". $language.'</td>';
        if ($i%3 == 2){
            $html .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    //use $i%3 to figure out how to finish off table
    if ($i%3 == 0){
        $html = substr($html, 0, -5);//get rid of last <tr> tag
    } elseif($i%3 == 2) {
        $html .= '<td>&nbsp;</td><tr>';
    } else {
        $html .= '<td span="2">&nbsp;</td><tr>';
    }
    echo $html;
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: This appears to be unnecessary, as it's still valid HTML to have a table row with fewer cells than another row. From the spec: "If the column count for the table is greater than the number of cells for a given row (after including cells for spanned rows), the missing cells are treated as occurring on the right hand side of the table and rendered as empty cells."

Comment: @jcsanyi - You're right. I was using a `foreach` loop when I wrote it, and the value of `$key` ends up 1 less than `$i`. Thanks for the heads up. I just edited it.